# Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb:" or "mongodb+srv://

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aws-serverless

Deploying my API then attempting to send a GET request to the DB results in `Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection` `Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb:" or "mongodb+srv://`

My db.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

let connection_uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
let cachedMongoConn = null;

export const connectToDatabase = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connection
      .on("error", (error) => {
        console.log("Error: connection to DB failed");
        reject(error);
      })
      .on("close", () => {
        console.log("Error: Connection to DB lost");
        process.exit(1);
      })
      // Connected to DB
      .once("open", () => {
        // Display connection information
        const infos = mongoose.connections;

        infos.map((info) =>
          console.log(`Connected to ${info.host}:${info.port}/${info.name}`)
        );
        // Return successful promise
        resolve(cachedMongoConn);
      });
    if (!cachedMongoConn) {
      cachedMongoConn = mongoose.connect(connection_uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        connectTimeoutMS: 60000,
        bufferCommands: false, 
      });
    } else {
      console.log("MongoDB: using cached database instance");
      resolve(cachedMongoConn);
    }
  });
};
```

.env

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://Username:Password:...
```

Everything "looks" correct and the connection string in the .env file is in the right format. So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you setup the `dotenv` configuration?

Comment: try logging the uri the line before connecting.

Comment: How do i log the uri...console.log()?

Comment: Could you please share what are you using to deploy your functions? Are you including the `.env` file inside your deployment package?

Comment: I'm using serverless to deploy to AWS and local `sls offline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this same issue, removing the quotes before the URI link, solved it.

The problem is that the variable is most likely not formatted correctly.

Remove the spaces, the quotes, and the semi-colon at the end.

This

```
CONNECTION_URL =
"mongodb+srv://<UserName>:<Password>@cluster0.v5qzigz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Becomes this

```
CONNECTION_URL=mongodb+srv://<UserName>:<Password>@cluster0.v5qzigz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

credits to [dev mikeym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1884023/mikeym)

Then the connection should work